# Is there a Force-focused lightsaber style more warrior oriented than Niman?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, fictional-fight-style

Niman seems to be the most Force centric style but I believe that it's lacking in both offense and defense, and it doesn't have a good record either, most of Niman's specialists died on the first battle of Geonosis.

Comment: What do you mean, mate?

Comment: As opposed to the lightsaber style used by lumberjacks?

Comment: Niman is the Form of the diplomat, this form isn't really useful to fight other trained saber users or a large number of foes, it's kind of all around, this Form is the only formal Form of combat that incorporates Force Powers into the style, for instance, a Slash followed by a Force Push or Force Pull into an impaling strike.

What I mean by warrior oriented and Force centric is that it incorporates Force Powers into the style and it's more effective in a combat situation than Niman, Niman being more to deal with pirates and the likes that you'd find in a diplomatic mission.

Comment: This may be a matter of your own opinion, so perhaps check out the DK factbook ["Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) It describes a number (maybe 7?) of canon light saber forms.

Comment: I have The Jedi Path where it describes the 7 forms, it's not really an opinion, it's a fact that Niman is most used by Diplomatic Jedi that don't spend too much fighting so the Form is relatively weak when compared to any other, to further show evidence, most of the casualties in the First Battle of Geonosis where Niman specialists.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that there's no real offensive Form focused on using the Force along the Saber, Sidious is better known for his Force Powers than Saber styles so the form I'm searching for could be a Sith Style, the 3 characters that I can think of that mix their Force Powers into their styles are all Sith anyways, Galen Marek, Revan and Sidious.

Comment: The dupe directly addresses both the weakness of Niman as well as highlighting some more martial styles.